# How can you change a variable inside a function scope? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am making and idle game and what I want to do is to change the value of a variable inside a function wich is called by an event listener like this:

```
const foo = (x) =>{
    x = x + 1;
}
foofoo.addEventListener("click", function(){foo(x)})
```

where x is a variable is this possible?

Comment: `x` is passed by value, so it's a copy. Use an object, return a value or make it global (the second option is by far the best).

Comment: `let x; ... const foo = () => { x++ };`?

Comment: @ggorlen I am running this from an eventlistener how can I do that?

Comment: Edit your question to provide a [mcve] that reproduces what you're trying to accomplish, otherwise it's a bit hard to say in a helpful way that wouldn't be overly general.